# Let CMake rescan a directory (Usage of GLOB_RECURSE)

Tags: cmake, glob

When using GLOB_RECURSE to add a certain directory structure to a list, CMake doesn't detect if new files are added to the directory.

How can I make CMake rescan the directory structure on every run, so that new files are detected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `touch CMakeLists.txt` whenever you change the directory contents.

What you're doing goes counter to official advice, but I do it too. You could knock up a script [which monitors a directory for changes](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/Linux-Inotify2-1.22/Inotify2.pm), but CMake considers this to be not its business.

The reason, I suspect, is that directory modification timestamp attributes aren't very cross-platform.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you. Do you know if GLOB does detect new files automatically?